# How do I align textPosition for a label?

Tags: java-me, label, midlet, lwuit

I wonder if it is possible to set `textPosition()` for a `Label` that includes an `Image` and a text part so that the text is both TOP and LEFT. The problem I have now is that I need the text to be TOP but when that is selected the text is centered over the image. My wish is that the text is over the image but to the left and not centered. I wonder if there is a way to do this?

I have tried to add the text to one `Label` and the image to another `Label` and then contain them in a container but the problem is then that the alignment will be the same for all the items(text over image) and item over item. So it will not be possible to see if the text over the second image is part of the first image or the second.

Thanks.

---

Ok so this is what I mean. This is the current behaviour:

```
Label item = new Label();
item.setIcon(icon);
item.setText("House:");
item.setTextPosition(TOP);
```

Result:

```
House:

 /\
```

The wanted behaviour is:

```
Label item = new Label();
item.setIcon(icon);
item.setText("House:");
item.setTextPosition(TOP);
item.setTextPosition(LEFT);
```

House:

```
/\
```

I need to set TextPosition to both Top and left, is that possible? Or is there any otherway I can get this behaviour. If I use a container the result will be:

House:

```
/\
```

House:

```
/\
```

What I want is that the alignment between "House:" and /\ is separate from "House:" and the /\ above.

I hope this makes any sense. Hard to explain it in a good way. Thanks for any help you can give me.

Comment: It would help if you had code sample that illustrates the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use two labels within a container to achieve that, one for the icon and another for the text. There are infinite number of configurations for things like that, the more support we add the more complex and slow label rendering becomes and its API becomes more convoluted.